# Cannot install Ubuntu 18.04 on Microsoft Surface Pro 7

Tags: intel, microsoft, surface

The installation USB launches, but stops with the following screen:

"hw perf events fixed 4 > max(3), clipping!"

I read somewhere, this is Linux's issue with the Intel Gen 10th. Ubuntu 19.10 and CentOS-8 didn't work either.

Please Ubuntu, fix this issue.

Comment: Have a look at this. https://github.com/jakeday/linux-surface It does not list surface 7, but can open a new issue.

Comment: Thanks, but that github page only provides a bunch of lib to make touch and pen function. I cannot install (so far any) Linux to begin with.

Answer (score 1):

I decided to go with WSL (Windows Subsystem for Linux, Ubuntu version) plus Xming X Server to get all the graphical functionalities. I can even use my pen to draw on Linux's Gimp using this combo. I got all the benefits of having a Linux and at the same time preserving the unique interface that Surface Pro 7 offers.